# Ionic mobile development; Error when preparing android in Ionic

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting an error when I add android platform and prepare android.

When I run the following command :-

```
 ionic capacitor add android
```

I get following error:-

> [error] "android" platform already exists.
> To add a new "android" platform, please remove "D:\ionic\myapp\android"
> and run this command again.
> WARNING! your native IDE project will be completely removed. [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
> capacitor.cmd add android exited with exit code 1.

I updated the android by using the following command:-

```
ionic capacitor update android
```

It updated my android : -

> capacitor.cmd update android  √ Updating Android plugins in 73.77ms
> Found 0 Capacitor plugins for android:  √ update android in 473.61ms
> Update finished in 0.593s

Then I tried to prepare the android to start in Android studio :-

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

I got the following error:-

> cordova.cmd platform add android --save Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could
> not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-14T09_02_55_668Z-debug.log
> at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:135:23)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
> at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
> at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {   stderr: 'npm ERR! code
> ENOLOCAL\n' +
> 'npm ERR! Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.\n' +
> '\n' +
> 'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
> 'npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-14T09_02_55_668Z-debug.log\n',
> code: 1 } [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
> cordova.cmd platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.
> Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

I tried to remove cordova and install again. But it is not working.

Have I missed any plugin. I have added the capacitor in the beginning of the project.

Could anyone please suggest any solution ?

Comment: if you are using capacitor then why you are executing cordova command `ionic cordova prepare android`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start ionic app on Android Studio, execute below command.

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

Comment: Hey  Vivek Jain, you are 100% correct. I was using  wrong command. Thank you for saving my day. I am learning Ionic, I missed the line in documents that says, run this command if cordova. Thank you again.